# What is the meaning of complex-valued entropy?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, entropy, complex-numbers

I was wondering, from Boltzmann Formula, 
$$S = k \ln{W}$$
where $k$ is Boltzmann's constant, what happens if $W$ is negative value. If $W$ is a negative value, then it can be rewritten as
$$-W = e^{in\pi}W$$
where n is an odd integer. 
Thus, 
$$S = kln(-W) = kln(e^{in \pi}W)= k[ln(e^{in \pi})+ln(W)] = k[in\pi+ln(W)]$$

Does this describe anything in nature? What is the meaning of complex-valued entropy? Lastly what is the meaning of the value n?

Comment: $W$ is the number of accessible microstates, or phase space volume. How could that become negative?

Comment: Consider $\delta S$. Imagine that at one point you have W = -5 and at another, W = -10. Then $\delta S = kln(-10) - kln(-5) = k[in \pi +ln(10) - in \pi -ln(5) = k ln(2)$ Which is obviously REAL valued. I don't know why W would be negative, but nobody every said |W|. I do have a thought, what if a negative state represents a state that is not considered to be possible. For example, what if a mixture of two chemicals undergoes separation through quantum tunneling and thus the entropy of the universe was actually reduced. This probability is near zero but still possible. Just a curiosity.

Comment: microstates are just possible configurations, so if you flip a coin twice you have results HH, TH, HT, and TT, so 4 microstates. what could you mean by 4 negative microstates in that scenario? What is a negative configuration?
two chemicals separating is possible, just usually very unlikely, they would still have the same possible microstates

Comment: At the same time, complex-valued inverse temperature $\beta$ and fugacity  $z$ have some meaning  in statistical physics, for example, they give information about the properties of phase transitions.